# Insert new collection after function runs on server

Tags: meteor

When I return the geocode from googles API I'm trying to save it into my database. I've been trying to use the code below, to just insert a Test document with no luck. I think it has something to do with meteor being asynchronous. If I run the insert function before the `googleMapsClient.geocode` function it works fine. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'myTestFunction'() {
    googleMapsClient.geocode({
      address: 'test address'
    }, function(err, response) {
      if (!err) {
        Test.insert({test: 'test name'});
      }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: How do you call this method?
Are you doing in on Meteor.startup ?
You should.

Comment: It's in my api folder under methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now where you got the idea to run the NPM library on the client side, but this is not what you really want here. You should be getting some errors on the server side of your meteor instance when you run the initial piece of code you gave us here. The problem is that the google npm library runs in it's own thread, this prevents us from using Meteor's methods. The easiest thing you could do is wrap the function with `Meteor.wrapAsync` so it would look something like this.

```
try {
  var wrappedGeocode = Meteor.wrapAsync(googleMapsClient.geocode);
  var results = wrappedGeocode({ address : "testAddress" });
  console.log("results ", results);
  Test.insert({ test : results });
} catch (err) {
  throw new Meteor.Error('error code', 'error message');
}
```

You can find more info by [looking at this thread](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-wrapasync-over-specific-npm-package-method/30801/18), there are others dealing with the same issue as well

Answer (score 0):

You should run the googleMapsClient.geocode() function on the client side, and the Test.insert() function on the server side (via a method). Try this:

Server side

```
Meteor.methods({
  'insertIntoTest'(json) {
    Test.insert({results: json.results});
  }
});
```

Client side

```
googleMapsClient.geocode({
  address: 'test address'
}, function(err, response) {
  if (!err) {
    Meteor.call('insertIntoTest', response.json);
  }
});
```

Comment: Silly question, it errors on the client. How do I import googleMapsClient?

Comment: If I run this on the client side I get the error `Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=20test&key=AIzaSyDwk6NEL_8Pg0gUeqMrGTK35g0I5ApwumY: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor Methods` should be available on the both the `server` and `client` sides. Therefore make sure that your method is accessible by server; via proper importing on `/server/main.js` or proper [folder structuring](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html). 
(If a method contains a secret logic run on the server, it should be isolated from the method runs on both server & client, though)

Comment: No real need for the method to be available on the client, other than "latency compensation". A method that is not available on the client is perfectly callable, but it's not simulated on the client.

Comment: That's true and making a Meteor Method available to the both side is to implement the "Optimistic UI" feature. What I am saying in the answer is; "you cannot define your Meteor Method only on the client side."